# Android Rotate Animation

Tags: android

I am working on a simple compass app. I am using a rotate animation to rotate an image but when I rotate around from 0 to 360 degrees the image flips back around to start over at 0 degrees. How do I stop the image from rotating backwards to 0 degrees.

```
float[] mGravity;
float[] mGeomagnetic;
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
        mGravity = lowPass(event.values, mGravity);
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD)
        mGeomagnetic = lowPass(event.values, mGeomagnetic);
    if (mGravity != null && mGeomagnetic != null) {
        float R[] = new float[9];
        float I[] = new float[9];
        boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, I, mGravity, mGeomagnetic);
        if (success) {
            float orientation[] = new float[3];
            SensorManager.getOrientation(R, orientation);

            //Convert azimuth to degrees
            float azimuthInDegrees = (float) (Math.toDegrees(orientation[0])+360)%360;


            //Show coord name
            String coordNames[] = {"N","NNE", "NE","ENE","E", "ESE","SE","SSE", "S","SSW", "SW","WSW", "W","WNW", "NW","NNW", "N"};
            double directionid = Math.round(azimuthInDegrees / 22.5);
            // no of array contain 360/16=22.5
            if (directionid < 0) {
                directionid = directionid + 16;
                //no. of contains in array
            }
            String compasLoc = coordNames[(int) directionid];

            tvHeading.setText("Heading: " + Float.toString(Math.round(azimuthInDegrees)) + " " + compasLoc);

            // create a rotation animation (reverse turn degree degrees)
            RotateAnimation ra = new RotateAnimation(
                    currentDegree,
                    -azimuthInDegrees,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                    0.5f);

            // how long the animation will take place
            ra.setDuration(210);
            // set the animation after the end of the reservation status
            ra.setFillAfter(true);
            // Start the animation
            image.startAnimation(ra);
            currentDegree = -azimuthInDegrees;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your source code?

Comment: Do you mean that after the 360° rotation it rotates back to its starting position in the opposite direction?

Comment: Yes thats right it rotates back to its starting position at 360

Comment: What does `currentDegree = -azimuthInDegrees;` do?

Answer (score 0):

I test your animation code with a static `toDegrees` value

```
RotateAnimation ra = new RotateAnimation(
    15,
    -30, // a static vaule
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
    0.5f,
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
    0.5f);
```

and the image rotate to right degree, the code snippet works normally.
You should add log to debug how `startAnimation` is invoked. Maybe `onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)` is invoked again and cause the image rotate backwards.